# Integration of Node.js and Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, express

I have done considerable reading on both Node.js and Backbone.js; I've read some tutorials and done the relevant courses on Code School. I feel that I've got a pretty good idea of the functions that each technology serves in the context of a web application.

My problem is that I don't really know how to integrate the two technologies and use them in tandem. I would really appreciate if someone could point me to a resource which goes through the entire development of an application using Node, MongoDB, and Backbone together.

Many thanks

Answer (score 29):

This is a good tutorial that shows how to setup that entire stack.

http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/

In short...

#### Node.js

You can use a library like [restify](http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/) to provide a restful API for your client-side Backbone application.  It can also serve your static assets for your Backbone application.  The example uses restify, but could be accomplished with other libraries like [express](http://expressjs.com/).

#### Mongoose

[Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) is a javascript abstraction layer for MongoDB.  This provides an easy way to interact with MongoDB from Node.js.

#### Backbone

Your Backbone application can utilize your **restify** node.js backend to handle the model synchronization.  You should have plenty of control to setup the routes via **restify** in a way that makes Backbone happy.

Comment: http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/ is a broken link :(

Answer (score 5):

This ebook could be useful (it's on Backbone, but uses Node for the backend):

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

You also may want to look at this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Building-Node-Applications-MongoDB-Backbone/dp/1449337392](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449337392)

Comment: I would not recommend the second suggestion offered above(Building Node Applications with MongoDB and Backbone) as it lacks clarity and needs serious editing.Definitely not for people who are just starting to build applications in node.

Comment: Ahh I see, the idea behind building a social network is all great, and there are some great guidelines on managing your files well, however the code parts are presented in pieces and for a beginner it may be very difficult to see how the pieces fit together.

Comment: I have some experience developing with Rails. It's just a little confusing in this new environment because Rails automatically makes a lot of these connections for you. Just thought I'd add that, in case that would change your recommendations

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Node Cellar Source](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/nodecellar-sample-application-with-backbone-js-twitter-bootstrap-node-js-express-and-mongodb/).

There is not much explanation about the code, but the app is simple enough to get started and understand the basics layouts of node / backbone

It is, i think, just between an 'Hello World' code and a full app.

Answer (score 1):

I use for ap in backbone yeoman https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone and you use it with node.js too

Answer (score 0):

create rest api: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

code backbone on the client: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/nodecellar-sample-application-with-backbone-js-twitter-bootstrap-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

the backbonetutorials.com restify one is out of date. It's best to use express, especially if you plan to do any authorization. It's also more widely used

Answer (score 0):

This is a comprehensive tutorial on rolling your own blog with Nodejs, Mongodb and expressjs
http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb
It's old but with a little effort you can get it to work and learn at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be the most up to date material on using Backbone.js with node
http://amzn.to/1DygKlJ